# Checkbox for displaying all skills in mvc3 razor databasefirst

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, sql-server-2008

I am trying to display selected skills in my create page. I have the database, I given the connection from the model but i am getting all the skills but when I was selected the skills those are not saving dont know what the problem Can anyone help me? View code is

```
<div class="editor-field">
        @{ 
   IEnumerable<SelectListItem> skill = ViewBag.skill;
   foreach (var item in skill)
   {
            @Html.CheckBox("Skills", false, new { value = item.Value });                                                             
            <input type="checkbox" name="skillsId" value="@item.Text" /> 
            <label>@item.Text</label>  
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Skills)
   }
        }
       </div>
```

and controller code is

```
int SId = Convert.ToInt32(emp.Skills);
var Sname = (from sn in db.TblSkills
            where sn.SkillsId == SId
            select sn.Skills).SingleOrDefault();
```

Comment: Please post your Model and complete Controller action... Your checkboxes in your view are a mess, but let us help you with more complete code ;)

Comment: the code is too long where can I post? I am new to this!!!!

Comment: How are passing info from Controller to view? Are you using Models or just using ViewBag?  You can post the controller actions signature at least, I mean... when the view post your skill data back to server you should have set a correct action method params.  So... post your code editing your answer, nevermind if it long... you/we can always remove the part is not relevant.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this code. It is  helpful to you.

```
<%: Html.CheckBox("Skills", Model.Skills.HasValue ?  Model.Skills.Value : false)%> Skills
```